# Text game - Game Loop

Tags: python, loops

```
print "Welcome to the game. In the game you can 'look around' and 'examine things'."
print "There is also some hidden actions."
print "You wake up."

input = raw_input("> ")

haveKey = False
applesExist = True


if input == "look around":
    print "You are in a dusty cell. There is a barrel in the corner of the room, an unmade bed,"
    print "a cabinet and chest. There is also a cell door."
elif haveKey == False and input == "open door":
    print "The door is locked."
elif haveKey == True and input == "open door":
    print "You open the door, walk out and immediately gets shot with an arrow. You won, kinda."
elif input == "examine barrel":
     print "There is apples in the barrel."
elif applesExist == True and input == "eat apple":
    print "Mmmmh, that was yummy! But now there are no apples left..."
    applesExist = False
elif applesExist == False and input == "eat apple":
    print "sury, u et al aples befur!!1111"
elif input == "examine bed":
    print "The bed is unmade, and has very dusty sheets. This place really needs a maid."
elif input == "sleep on bed":
     print "You lie down and try to sleep, but you can't because of all the bugs crawling on you."
elif input == "examine chest":
     print "There is a key in the chest."
elif input == "take key":
    haveKey = True
    print "You take the key."
elif input == "examine cabinet":
     print "The cabinet is made of dark oak wood. There is a endless cup of tea in it."
elif input == "drink tea":
    print "You put some tea in your mouth, but immediately spit it out."
    print "It seems it has been here for quite some time."
else:
    print "Huh, what did you say? Didn't catch that."
```

Um, hi. I need help. As you can see this is a very basic text game that
lets the player interact with the environment. I plan to expand on the
interacting thing and with that I need no help. But with the game loop I do. You probably realize, but for those that don't, every time I write a command the program closes. I've been told that I need a game loop to do this, but I have no idea how.

Something I need to tell you, compared to you, I'm kinda retarded. I'm no programming genius, I just simply enjoy programming. So please, just say *how*, not *why*. I'll figure that out myself, since I have all the time in the world. And if I ever need to know *why*, then I'll ask you again! =D

Comment: You *do* know about loops and how to make one? For example, making a loop the iterates *while* some condition is true?

Comment: Yes, kinda =D. I know how to make something loop forever, or until a boolean change, but that's my limit =)

Comment: Then think about for a while (pun not intended): You make a loop that loops while the user don't want to quit, it's as simple as that. You need a variable which is initialized to `True`, and stays `True` until the user enters a command to quit, and use that variable as the loop condition.

Comment: Um, this is the thing I wanted to avoid, not-so-clear instructions. As I said, please write *why*, for (pun intended) I'm retarded compared to you.

Comment: The *why* is that code in Python is, in the absence of loops, strict sequential. The code is executed from top to bottom, and in your program that means that once the big if/else-if chain is done the program will exit. Putting the whole thing in a loop will cause the program to ask the user for input and run your code over and over until the loop condition is false, and then the program will continue to its exit. That is the "why" of the loop really.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a loop like while. You have to get input from inside of the loop. And you have to check whether game is over or not. Input will be reset automatically because of `raw_input()` function:

```
print "Welcome to the game. In the game you can 'look around' and 'examine things'."
print "There is also some hidden actions."
print "You wake up."

haveKey = False
applesExist = True
gameover = False

while gameover == False:
    input = raw_input("> ")
    if input == "look around":
        print "You are in a dusty cell. There is a barrel in the corner of the room, an unmade bed,"
        print "a cabinet and chest. There is also a cell door."
    elif haveKey == False and input == "open door":
        print "The door is locked."
    elif haveKey == True and input == "open door":
        print "You open the door, walk out and immediately gets shot with an arrow. You won, kinda."
    elif input == "examine barrel":
         print "There is apples in the barrel."
    elif applesExist == True and input == "eat apple":
        print "Mmmmh, that was yummy! But now there are no apples left..."
        applesExist = False
    elif applesExist == False and input == "eat apple":
        print "sury, u et al aples befur!!1111"
    elif input == "examine bed":
        print "The bed is unmade, and has very dusty sheets. This place really needs a maid."
    elif input == "sleep on bed":
         print "You lie down and try to sleep, but you can't because of all the bugs crawling on you."
    elif input == "examine chest":
         print "There is a key in the chest."
    elif input == "take key":
        haveKey = True
        print "You take the key."
    elif input == "examine cabinet":
         print "The cabinet is made of dark oak wood. There is a endless cup of tea in it."
         gameover = True
    elif input == "drink tea":
        print "You put some tea in your mouth, but immediately spit it out."
```

Comment: Why the "reset" of the input string at the end of the loop? It will be "reset" first thing once the loop starts over anyway.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yeah you right I made a mistake because of my test order. don't need this line: `input = 0`

Comment: No probs, sorry for late reply, went to resturaunt and ate some sushi. But I'll keep the: input = 0 since it reminds me of you. I love you. Thanks for solving my trivial problem =D

Comment: @Elsvaer Can you please mark my answer as correct answer? Thanks!